# Raw SQL with Express without ORMs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, architecture, software-design

I want to use raw SQL queries in my application but I have some questions on how to structure my application.

Some background:

1. I am writing a JSON API with Express and Postgres.
2. I am not currently using an ORM. I have used Sequelize before, but I don't believe the queries are optimized so I am hesitant to use it.
3. I am using camelCase in my code but Postgres is case-insensitive, so for readability, I have used under_scores in my DB tables. I constantly have to do queries like:

   `SELECT first_name AS "firstName" from users;`

   When the queries get larger, it is almost impossible to read since there is no syntax highlighting of SQL in js string templates.
4. I feel there is too much repetition in my queries, but that is expected.

What I am thinking:

1. I was not able to find a Visual Studio Code extension that can highlight SQL inside js files and strings. If there was one, I might get by.
2. I might write all my queries in .sql files, so that I can have syntax highlighting and load them all into memory when my application starts to prevent too many IO operations, since it would be against the reasoning why I am using raw SQL in the first place.

Anyone had this issue before? How do you structure your application when using raw SQL with Postgres and Express?

Answer (score 0):

1. Definitely keep all the sql scripts in the corresponding `.sql` files.
2. Stick to a meaningfull naming convention. Come up with one you feel comfortable with: in future it will allow to build helpful tools around your codebase doing a lot of boring stuff automatically and making you much happier.
3. In case you're getting complicated rapidly, generate at least some of the duplicate/commonly used sql. Consider having some simple placeholders in your files like `{{ firstName }}` which is translated into `first_name AS "firstName"`. Such a translation should happen only once - when you lode source `.sql`. This is more sophisticated and highly depends upon your tasks kind. Sometimes such an approach is useless, sometimes - useful.

Comment: I am worried about the IO, if any time my application needs to do a query, it needs to read a file, that would seriously impact the latency. Add the templating of my sql queries and we have a problem. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: @KorayGocmen, it should **not** read a source file every time. Cache raw string (before placeholders were translated into concrete values). Keep appropriate `ISqlSourceFile` close to database-related code. Once again, you must perform IO only once.